# Making variable from HTML-file work in PHP-file

Tags: php, html

I have two rather simple files. The first is an HTML-file like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
Search for: <input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The second file is test.php and it looks like this:

```
<?
       $filepath = "/usr/sbin";
       exec("ONE $search -command $filepath ");
       fopen($filepath, rw);
?>
```

My problem is that I want to use the argument "search" given in the HTML-form as value of variable in the PHP-script. ONE is a search script I made that takes one argument and I want it to be "$search".

Could this be done and if so how?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be in `$_POST["search"]`, I think. But be very wary about taking user-entered data and passing it into an `exec` call.

Comment: Do not post the [*same question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517367/why-doesnt-php-accept-command-with-argument-1) more than once - it will be considered as SPAM.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
exec("ONE " . $_POST['search']. " -command $filepath ");
```

**UPDATE**:
You have another error, your following line:

```
fopen($filepath, rw);
```

should be like this:

```
fopen($filepath, "rw");
```

cause the second parameter to `fopen()` should be passed as a string.

**UPDATE 2**:
So as it seems, the OP want the output of the command to be printed on the page, for that you have to use [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead of `exec()` , like so:

```
passthru("ONE " . $_POST['search']. " -command $filepath ");
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" isn't very helpful. Does it error? Do nothing?

Comment: The PHP-file should find a couple of files containing the word given in "search", but it gives a blank page. I guess the variable isn't taken.

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in test.php on line 3

Comment: It seems an error in your fopen call, see the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I've done the corrections and if I run php test.php in a terminal there's no more errors except that an argument is missing and so it should be. When I fill in a searchword in the HTML-file then clicking "Search" it pops right over to the test.php - but seemingly without getting any variable since the output is blank just like when I run php test.php.

Comment: I don't see your code creating any output, it doesn't do any **echo** , so a blank page is the expected result.

Comment: Well, how come when the line exec("ETT " . $_REQUEST['search']. " -command $filepath "); will be switched to exec("ETT "searchword" -command $filepath ");, then there will be output?

Comment: When I add another line echo($_REQUEST['search']); it throws back my searchword from the HTML-file, so the variable does roll over to the PHP-file, but it's not accepted as an argument to the command for some reason.

Comment: I've updated my answer responding about how you can show the output of your command on the webpage.

Comment: Thank you so much for all help. I think the problem is that the variable "search" simply isn't recognized as an argument to the ONE command. Why? It's beyond my understanding.

Comment: Will it be because you are not prepending it with a dash ? like you do for "-command" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access that variable by using `$_POST['search']`

Before you use it in a shell call you should make sure that it won't damage your system.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Do I need to put it in a new variables like this: search1 = $_POST['search'] or search1 = $($_POST['search']) ?