# Why doesn't PHP accept command with argument $1

Tags: php, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making variable from HTML-file work in PHP-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500129/making-variable-from-html-file-work-in-php-file)

I have another file (HTML-file) that passes an argument to this PHP-file. It does so I have checked it with "echo" and it throws back the same argument I wrote in the HTML-file, so so far, so good. The PHP-file looks like this.

```
<?
       $filepath = "/usr/sbin";
       exec("ONE $search -command $filepath ");
       fopen($filepath, "rw");
?>
```

The command "ONE" which is a bash-script I wrote to do some "greps" in files takes one argument and that is "$search" which in deed is passed over to this PHP-file. And if I exchange "$search" to the actual word "searchword" it works like a charm. Why doesn't it accept "$search" as argument? It just seem to ignore it and throws back a blank page, but if I use "searchword" it gives back just what I want.

Comment: Where do you define `$search`?

Comment: not a duplicate, it's an elaboration

Comment: it's defined as "name" in the HTML-file                                                             <form action="test.php" method="post">
Search for: <input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

Comment: So you've defined it as `$search = $_REQUEST["search"];`, then?

Comment: Well, when I put a line echo($_POST['search']); it will throw up my "searchword" passed from the HTML-page, so the variable is there for sure, but it will not become the argument of my command:(

Comment: Have you actually assigned the value of `$_POST['search']` to `$search`?

Comment: Yes, it is assigned and I can either echo $search; or echo($_POST['search']); and it will both give me "searchword" from HTML-file.

Comment: What is output when you change the `exec` to `echo`?

Comment: First I must say, that was a clever question:) Second, it shows just as I suspected: "ONE -command /usr/sbin" whereas if I used "searchword" instead of "$search" it will show "ONE searchword -command /usr/sbin", The argument isn't taken!

Comment: Try explicitly building the query, in that case: `$cmd = "ONE " . $_POST["search"] . "-command " . $filepath; exec($cmd);`. Though I can't for the life of me figure out why it's adding $filepath to the string but not $search.

Comment: You're probably better off trying to eliminate the quotes to start with - I've no idea where they're coming from. I'd suggest echoing out the $_POST version and the variable, and see if either of those have quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in `fopen` (probably a transcription error).

Do you mean to use `$_REQUEST['search']` as opposed to just `$search`?  By "HTML-file that passes an argument to this PHP-file" I assume you mean via a link or asynchronous request of some kind.  If that's the case, you should use `escapeshellarg`.

Comment: Sorry, what's an escapeshellarg?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
exec("ONE {$search} -command {$filepath} ");
```

Does it work?

Comment: {$var} is used only when concatained with other chars. Such as `echo "{$var}s";`, avoiding PHP to search $vars variable instead of $var.

Comment: Nice tries all of you, but it seems impossible to get PHP to accept the variable as an argument to the command. It's a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("ONE $search -command $filepath ");
```

trailing space?